# How interactive command line utilities actually work?

Tags: command-line, terminal

I grasp the basic concept of stdin, stdout, stderr and how programs work with a command line/terminal.

However, I've always wondered how utilities like `less` in Linux and `git log` work because they are interactive.

My current thought is that the program does not quit, writes to stdout, listens to key events and writes more to stdout until the user quits pressing `q` or sends the close signal.

Is my intuition right or is there more to it? Do they detect the amount of lines and characters per line to determine how much to output? And do they clear the screen always before output?

Comment: You probably want to look at Curses.  See e.g. http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses-intro.html

Answer (score 0):

Very interesting question, even if it's a bit open ended.

As mentioned by @tripleee, [ncurses](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses-intro.html) is a foundational library for interactive CLI apps.

---

### A bit of history ...

***Terminal == "printer" ...***

To understand POSIX "terminals", you have to consider their history ... more specifically, you need to think about what a "terminal" meant in the 70's where you'd have a keyboard+printer attached to a serial cable.  As you type, a stream of bytes flows to the mainframe which echos them back to the printer causing the printer to echo the command as you type it.  Then, typically after pressing ENTER, the mainframe would go off and do some work and then send output back to be printed.  Since it basically a glorified dot-matrix printer, we are talking append-only here.  There was no "painting the screen" or anything fancy like that.

Try this:

```
echo -e "Hi  there\rBye"
```

and you'll see it print "Bye there".  "\r" is a carriage return with no line feed.  A [carriage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carriage_control_tape) is that printer part that moves back and forth in an old dot-matrix printer and actually does the printing.  So if you return the carriage back to the left side of the page and fail to advance the paper (ie, "line feed"), then you will start printing over the current line of text.  "terminal" == "printer".

***Monitors and software terminals ... still line-oriented***

So flash forward a bit and a revolutionary tech called "monitors" comes about where you have a virtualized terminal display that can be rewritten.  So like all good tech, we innovated incrementally by adding more and more special escape codes.  For example, check out the [ANSI color codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#Colors).  If you are on a terminal that doesn't recognize those escape codes, you'll see a bunch of gibberish in the output from those uninterpreted codes:

```
    "methodName": ESC[32m"newInstance"ESC[39m,
    "fileName": ESC[32m"NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java"ESC[39m,
    "className": ESC[32m"sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl"ESC[39m,
    "nativeMethod": ESC[33mfalseESC[39m,
```

When your terminal sees '\033' (ESC), '[', ..., 'm', it interprets it as a command to change the color.  Try this:

```
 echo  -e "\033[32mgreen\033[39m"
```

So anyways, that's the history/legacy of the Unix terminal system which was then inherited by Linux and BSD (eg, macs), and semi-standardized as [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/contents.html).  Check out [termio.h](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/termios.h.html#tag_13_74) which defines the kernel interface for interacting with terminals.  Almost certainly, Linux/BSD have a bunch of more advanced functions that aren't fully standardized into POSIX.  While talking about "standards", there's also a bunch of de-facto terminal device protocol standards like the venerable [VT100](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VT100).  Software "terminal emulators" like SSH or PuTTY know how to speak VT100 and usually a bunch of more advanced dialects as well.

***Shoe-horning "interactive" onto a "line-oriented" interface ...***

So ... interactive ... that doesn't really fit well with a line-printer view of the world.  It's layered on top.  Input is easy; instead of automatically echoing each keystroke typed and waiting for ENTER (ala ["readline"](http://cnswww.cns.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/rltop.html)), we have the program consume keystrokes as they come in from the TTY.  Output is more complex.  Even though the fundamental abstraction is a *stream* of output, with enough escape codes you can repaint the screen by positioning the ["caret"](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Caret+%28computer%29) and writing new text on top of old text (just like with my "\r" example).  None of this is fun to implement yourself, especially when you want to support multiple environments with different escape codes. .... thus the libraries, of which ncurses is one of the most well known.  To get an idea of the funky magic done to *efficiently* render a dynamic screen into a line-oriented TTY, check out [Output and Screen Updating](http://frank.harvard.edu/~coldwell/ncurses/hackguide.html#output) from "A Hacker's Guide to NCURSES".